# Elastic Collision Between Equal Masses in Vector Form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

In the link below, there is a vector computation method for calculating post collision speeds for equal masses,

https://exploratoria.github.io/exhibits/mechanics/elastic-collisions-in-3d/index.html

The normal between two balls and relative velocity is

$$
\mathbf{n} = \frac{\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2}{|\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|}
$$

$$
\mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}} = \mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_2
$$

The relative velocity along the normal direction is

$$
\mathbf{v}_{\text{normal}} = (\mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{n}) \mathbf{n}
$$

The article says "For balls of equal mass, momentum and velocity are interchangeable". Then final velocities $\mathbf{v}_{1f}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{2f}$ are

$$
\mathbf{v}_{1f} = \mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{v}_{\text{norm}}, \quad \mathbf{v}_{2f} = \mathbf{v}_2 + \mathbf{v}_{\text{norm}}
$$

I am looking for a derivation of these vector formulas for final velocities, starting from convervation of momentum and energy assumption. I've seen a lot of literature on them using seperate components along the normal direction, etc, but no book seems to have the vector approach the post above has.

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot derive it simply from conservation of energy and momentum. Those prove $4$ equations in $6$ unknowns. You have to make some additional assumptions about the nature of the collision. This both the literature and this site do by assuming that there is no momentum transfer perpendicular to the "normal line".

Answer (score 2):

Momentum conservation is

$$
m_1 \vec{v}_1 + m_2 \vec{v}_2 = m_1 \vec{v}_1' + m_2 \vec{v}_2' 
$$

are $\vec{v}_1',\vec{v}_2'$ speed vectors after collision.

If momentum is conserved, loss of momentum in one ball is gain for another, and vica versa

$$
m_1 \vec{v}_1 = m_1 \vec{v}_1' - \Delta \vec{p}
$$

$$
m_2 \vec{v}_2 = m_2 \vec{v}_2' + \Delta \vec{p}
$$

In the idealized env momentum transfer can only happen on the line connecting centers of both balls. Say $P$ is the magnitude of momentum vector difference $\Delta \vec{p}$,

$$
\vec{v}_1' = \vec{v}_1 - (P / m_1) \vec{n}
\qquad (1)
$$

$$
\vec{v}_2' = \vec{v}_2 + (P / m_2) \vec{n}
\qquad (2)
$$

Find $P$ we find new speeds after collision.

[image]

The pic above shows $v_1$ ve $v_2$ are addition of two components each,
then $v_1,v_1',v_2,v_2'$ is,

$$
\vec{v}_1 = a_1 \vec{n} + b_1 \vec{q}, \qquad \vec{v}_2 = a_2 \vec{n} + b_2 \vec{q}
\qquad (3)
$$

$$
\vec{v}_1' = a_1' \vec{n} + b_1' \vec{q}, \qquad v_2' = a_2' \vec{n} + b_2' \vec{q}
\qquad (4)
$$

$a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are scalars.

Insert (3a) into (1)

$$
v_1' = a_1 \vec{n} + b_1 \vec{q} - (P/m_1) \vec{n}
$$

$$
 = (a_1 - p/m_1) \vec{n} + b_1 \vec{q}
$$

$$
v_2' = a_2 \vec{n} + b_2 \vec{q} + (P/m_2) \vec{n}
$$

$$
= (a_2 + P/m_2) \vec{n} + b_2 \vec{q}
$$

We know the form $\vec{v}_1' = a_1' \vec{n} + b_1' \vec{q}$,
$\vec{v}_2' = a_2' \vec{n} + b_2' \vec{q}$, look at the corresponding
parts,

$$
a_1' = a_1 - (P/m_1), \qquad b_1' = b_1
\qquad (5)
$$

$$
a_2' = a_2 + (P/m_2), \qquad b_2' = b_2
\qquad (6)
$$

For $P$ scalar, we can use energy conservation formula.  In single dim
$1/2 m v^2$, multidim $\frac{1}{2} m \cdot \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$, or
$\frac{1}{2} m <\vec{v},\vec{v}>$, or $\frac{1}{2} m ||v||^2$. Then,

$$
\frac{m_1}{2} ||v_1||^2 + \frac{m_2}{2} ||v_2||^2  =
\frac{m_1}{2} ||v_1'||^2 + \frac{m_2}{2} ||v_2'||^2 
$$

$||v_1||^2$ and $||v_1'||^2$ are easy, we look at the pic, ex $||v_1||$
is the hypotenus of a triangle with $a_1$ and $b_1$ sides.

$$
\frac{m_1}{2} (a_1^2+b_1^2) + \frac{m_2}{2} (a_2^2+b_2^2) =
\frac{m_1}{2} (a_1'^2+b_1'^2) + \frac{m_2}{2} (a_2'^2+b_2'^2) 
$$

Previous (5),(6) values are inserted into the formula above

$$
\frac{m_1}{2} (a_1^2+b_1^2) + \frac{m_2}{2} (a_2^2+b_2^2) =
\frac{m_1}{2} \left( \left(a_1-\frac{P}{m_1} \right)^2 + b_1^2 \right)  +
\frac{m_2}{2} \left( \left(a_2-\frac{P}{m_1} \right)^2 + b_2^2 \right) 
$$

$b_1^2$ are $b_2^2$ canceled. Rearrange with $P$ in LHS

$$
P = \frac{2 m_1 m_2 (a_1-a_2)}{m_1+m_2}
$$

Plug that into  (1) and (2)

$$
\vec{v}_1' = \vec{v}_1 - \frac{2 m_2 (a_1-a_2)}{m_1+m_2} \vec{n}
$$

$$
\vec{v}_2' = \vec{v}_2 + \frac{2 m_1 (a_1-a_2)}{m_1+m_2} \vec{n}
$$

The formula above is equivalent to

$$
\vec{v}_1' =
\vec{v}_1 - \frac{2m_2}{m_1+m_2}
\frac{< \vec{v}_1-\vec{v}_2, \vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2 >}{||\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2||^2}
(\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2)
$$

$$
\vec{v}_2' =
\vec{v}_2 - \frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}
\frac{< \vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1, \vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1 >}{||\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1||^2}
(\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2)
$$

Equal mass gives,

$$
v_1' = v_1 - \left( (v_1-v_2)  \cdot \vec{n} \right) \vec{n}
$$

$$
v_2' = v_2 - \left( (v_2-v_1)  \cdot \vec{n} \right) \vec{n}
$$

where $\vec{n} = \frac{x_1-x_2}{|x_1-x_2|}$

Reference

https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?print=1

Comment: Nice work! Though I would recommend using $\langle , \rangle$ instead of $<,>$ to denote the inner product. Code is ```\langle , \rangle```